# Flutter saving sqflite database to downloads directory

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, sqflite

The scenario is that the user needs to be able to save/backup their data. So that they can restore their data if ever needed in the future. Or even transfer data from one phone to another.

- **Users data is stored in a sqflite database.**

I want to avoid using any third party account set up like linking to google drive or something. Purely want the user to be able to download a file with their data in it.

I'm unsure on what option is best or what is even possible to do in Flutter.

Currently I'm thinking ideally I would want a button that saves the whole database to the users downloads directory. From there the user can do what they want with it.

- **Is it possible to save a sqflite database to the phones downloads directory?**

Or would it have to converted into another format before save?

If this were to be possible, is it also possible to replace the apps current db with a file that the user selects (their backed up db)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: @MrGandy please let me know if you're able to figure out this. I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @Irfan_Yusanif, no I never did. I ended up abandoning that project and moved onto something else that used Firestore for just about everything except color preferences, etc.